# iOS Swift Package Manager Support

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-ios, contentdistribution

Is there any plan regarding support MarketingCloudSDK iOS through Swift Package Manager?

Best Regards,

- Inácio.

Comment: If no one unearths any release notes or plans around this, it is probably a question best directed to Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, we have not prioritized releasing the iOS SDK with SPM, as Cocoapods is still the most popular dependency management system used by customers. Please file a voice of customer if this is important to your team.

Comment: That's depressing and shows a lack of support to this market considering SPM _is_ a 1st party supported dependency manager now.

Comment: Still nothing..? :s

Comment: The [release notes](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/) mention that SPM is supported as of version 8.0.0 (which also isn't on Cocoapods anymore). There is unfortunately no documentation on how to integrate it, and no Package.swift file in their [Github repository](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS).

Comment: Come on, its not so hard to add support for SPM as binary target. SPM is getting popular already and the ServiceSDK library is the only dependency we have without SPM support. Here is the apple guide https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/distributing_binary_frameworks_as_swift_packages

Comment: I've submitted a support case referencing all of this and will post the response I get here.

Comment: For SwiftPM support, the instructions to utilize this for the 8.* versions of the SDK are within the following documentation regarding migrating to the 8.x version from 7.x.

SFMCSdk Migration
https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-migration.html